# MediaElement player "success" callback is not being executed and possibly the "ended" event does not fire if flash fallback is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, internet-explorer, mediaelement.js

i use the following code to embed a video:

```
$('#trailer-dialog').mediaelementplayer({
        enablePluginDebug: false,
        // remove or reorder to change plugin priority
        plugins: ['flash','silverlight'],
        // specify to force MediaElement to use a particular video or audio type
        type: '',
        // path to Flash and Silverlight plugins
        pluginPath: '/build/',
        // name of flash file
        flashName: 'flashmediaelement.swf',
        // name of silverlight file
        silverlightName: 'silverlightmediaelement.xap',
        // default if the <video width> is not specified
        defaultVideoWidth: 1240,
        // default if the <video height> is not specified    
        defaultVideoHeight: 679,
        // overrides <video width>
        pluginWidth: -1,
        // overrides <video height>      
        pluginHeight: -1,
        // rate in milliseconds for Flash and Silverlight to fire the timeupdate event
        // larger number is less accurate, but less strain on plugin->JavaScript bridge
        timerRate: 250,
        success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {

            // add event listener
            mediaElement.addEventListener('ended', trailerEnded, false);

            // call the play method
            mediaElement.play();

        },
        // fires when a problem is detected
        error: function () {

        }

    });
```

this is the function to be executed when the event fires:

```
function trailerEnded(e){
    e.target.stop();
    $.cookie('trailer_played', 'true');
    $('#wrapper').css('display', 'block');
    $('#trailer').css('display', 'none');
    alert('test');
}
```

it is being executed in browsers which are able to display htm5 videos. but in IE 6-8 which use the flash fallback it doesn't work.

any ideas to fix this?

thanks

lukas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your version of mediaelementjs - latest version solved this for me.

Comment: I still have the problem on version 2.9.5

Comment: I still have the problem in 2.18.1. but I definitely had it working on a previous site. Did anyone work this out?